# JS: Collision Detection doesn't work when Ball is moving faster

Tags: javascript, performance, collision-detection, frame-rate, game-loop

I am currently trying to learn JavaScript and followed a tutorial on programming a Breakout game. I added some stuff after the tutorial. One of the things I added was that the ball becomes faster as the game progresses. Now I have the following problem.

My paddle is 10px thick but at some point the ball moves faster than 10px per frame/update. Because of that it often goes straight through the paddle insted of bouncing off of it. I already doubled the FPS/UPS from 60 to 120 and divided the ball speed by 2.

Of course I could increase the fps even more but I hope there is a more efficient/elegant version of handeling that problem.

Here is the function I use to let the ball bounce off the paddle:

```
function ballPaddleHandling() {
    var paddleTopEdgeY = canvas.height-PADDLE_DIST_FROM_EDGE;
    var paddleBottomEdgeY = paddleTopEdgeY + PADDLE_THICKNESS;
    var paddleLeftEdgeX = paddleX;
    var paddleRightEdgeX = paddleLeftEdgeX + PADDLE_WIDTH;
    if( ballY > paddleTopEdgeY && // below the top of paddle
        ballY < paddleBottomEdgeY && // above bottom of paddle
        ballX > paddleLeftEdgeX && // right of the left side of paddle
        ballX < paddleRightEdgeX) { // left of the left side of paddle

        ballSpeedY *= -1;

        var centerOfPaddleX = paddleX+PADDLE_WIDTH/2;
        var ballDistFromPaddleCenterX = ballX - centerOfPaddleX;
        ballSpeedX = ballDistFromPaddleCenterX * 0.35;

        if(bricksLeft == 0) {
            gameWon = true;
            //brickReset();
        } // out of bricks
    } // ball center inside paddle
} // end of ballPaddleHandling
```

If you want to look at all of my code you can do so here: https://jpst.it/1cHKn

Comment: Usually what we do is to calculate *whether the object (paddle) is in the path of the main object (ball)* instead of *whether the object overlaps the main object*. This simplifies the problem to whether two lines overlap. In your case, there are 4 lines on the paddle that you have to consider.

Comment: `ballY += ballSpeedY;` that part could move the ball through the paddle.  You should check if there will be a collision before you change ballY.

Comment: @James If the ball moves more than a paddle height per tick it might never 'collide' (above paddle before modifying Y, below it after)

Comment: @IrkenInvader right, that's my point.  But it's easy to check if the ball will move through the paddle before actually moving it.

Comment: oh, I thought you just meant do a intersect check before modifying Y

Comment: Checking if the path of the ball will collide with the paddle should be easy but I don't think it will solve the problem. I only want the ball to bounce if it touches the paddle but that may never happen because it "jumps" over the paddle when it is to fast.

Comment: I think they mean to construct lines for the ball start/stop location and each paddle corner start/stop.  (start = where it is before frame, stop = where it will end up after drawing the frame) super helpful bad paint drawing: https://i.imgur.com/yCzPrww.png

Answer (score 1):

**Maybe your problem is**: When you put the ball in the new position, the new coordinates are under the paddle, from one frame to other, so the ball never pass throuthg the paddle, it's just teleport between the frames to after the paddle.

**Maybe you'll need:** calc the trajectory of the ball, when detect that the ball will be after the paddle Y position, from one frame to other, check if the paddle is in the middle of the trajectory and put the ball on the new position in the top limit of the paddle

Answer (score 1):

You could use ray hit testing for this.
To simplify it, you just test against the upper face of the paddle.

```
function ballPaddleHandling() {
    var paddleTopEdgeY = canvas.height-PADDLE_DIST_FROM_EDGE;

    // calculate balls previous position
    var px = ballX - ballSpeedX
    var py = ballY - ballSpeedY

    // calculate trajectory angle
    var angle = getAngle(px,py,ballX,ballY) 

    // calulcate the length of the ray to test
    var length = getDist(px,py,ballX,ballY)

    // define the line to test as the upper face of the paddle
    var line = {x:paddleX, y:paddleTopEdgeY, w:PADDLE_WIDTH}

    // get position of hit, or false if no hit occured
    var hit_x = rayHitTestHorizontalLine(px,py,angle,length,line)

    if(hit_x!==false){
        ballSpeedY *= -1;

        var centerOfPaddleX = paddleX+PADDLE_WIDTH/2;
        var ballDistFromPaddleCenterX = hit_x - centerOfPaddleX;
        ballSpeedX = ballDistFromPaddleCenterX * 0.35;
    }
}

function rayHitTestHorizontalLine(px,py,angle,length,line){
    var dist = (line.y - py)/(-Math.cos(angle))
    if(dist>length)
        return false
    var hit_x = px+Math.sin(angle)*dist
    if(hit_x>=line.x && hit_x<=line.x+line.w)
        return hit_x
    else
        return false
}

function getAngle(x1,y1,x2,y2){
    return Math.atan2(y2-y1,x2-x1) + Math.PI/2
}

function getDist(x1,y1,x2,y2){
    return Math.sqrt((x2-x1)*(x2-x1)+(y2-y1)*(y2-y1))
}
```

Let me know if it works, I cant really test it myself.